# Jquery expand and collapse divs of same kind but only one

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

This has been asked alot. I am trying to expand and collapse a div with a +/- button. I have 5 dives with `class=="expanderContent"`.  When the below function runs due to a click, everyone of my 5 items expands or collapses.

Heading -
 inner
 inner
Heading2 -
 inner2
 inner2
Heading3 +
.....

When I click the + next to Heading2 I only want heading2 to open or close not all of them. The headings and content are inside the same div. So I am guessing I want to find out which `#expanderHead` was clicked and only open that sister `.expanderContent` not all the `.expanderContent`

```
$(document).ready(function(){
      $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
        $(".expanderContent").slideToggle('2000', "linear", function () {
            // Animation complete.
        });
        if ($("#expanderSign").text() == "+"){
          $("#expanderSign").html("−")
        }
        else {
          $("#expanderSign").text("+")
        }
      });
    });
```

HTML (These are identical data, but won't be in production)

```
      <div class="general_container_div">

    <div class="w-row page_wide_row header">
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div class="no_space_div"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>STATUS</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>PICKUP</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>DROPOFF</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>COURIER</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="w-row page_wide_row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
      <div>?</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>PICKING&nbsp;UP</p></div>
    <div><p>NOW</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>WhiteGLove</p></div>
    <div><p>34494 Washington Ave</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>Austin,&nbsp;TX</p></div>
      <div><p>231-444-5555</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>ORDER&nbsp;# 12345</p></div>
      <div><p>1 small/medium package</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>John&nbsp;Anderson</p></div>
    <div><p>3456 Elm Street</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>New York, New York</p></div>
      <div><p>312-444-2323</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>MEMO: Leave at front door.</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>Will Roth</p></div>
    <div><p>123-564-9876</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>NOTES: This is a really long note about how and where to leave something so I can text really long sentences and notes.&nbsp;</p><br></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;"><span id="expanderSign">+</span></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

      <div class="w-row page_wide_row header">
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div class="no_space_div"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>STATUS</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>PICKUP</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>DROPOFF</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>COURIER</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="w-row page_wide_row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
      <div>?</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>PICKING&nbsp;UP</p></div>
    <div><p>NOW</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>WhiteGLove</p></div>
    <div><p>34494 Washington Ave</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>Austin,&nbsp;TX</p></div>
      <div><p>231-444-5555</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>ORDER&nbsp;# 12345</p></div>
      <div><p>1 small/medium package</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>John&nbsp;Anderson</p></div>
    <div><p>3456 Elm Street</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>New York, New York</p></div>
      <div><p>312-444-2323</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>MEMO: Leave at front door.</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>Will Roth</p></div>
    <div><p>123-564-9876</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>NOTES: This is a really long note about how and where to leave something so I can text really long sentences and notes.&nbsp;</p><br></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;"><span id="expanderSign">+</span></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>

      <div class="w-row page_wide_row header">
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div class="no_space_div"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>STATUS</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>PICKUP</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>DROPOFF</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>COURIER</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="w-row page_wide_row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
      <div>?</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>PICKING&nbsp;UP</p></div>
    <div><p>NOW</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>WhiteGLove</p></div>
    <div><p>34494 Washington Ave</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>Austin,&nbsp;TX</p></div>
      <div><p>231-444-5555</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>ORDER&nbsp;# 12345</p></div>
      <div><p>1 small/medium package</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>John&nbsp;Anderson</p></div>
    <div><p>3456 Elm Street</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>New York, New York</p></div>
      <div><p>312-444-2323</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>MEMO: Leave at front door.</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>Will Roth</p></div>
    <div><p>123-564-9876</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>NOTES: This is a really long note about how and where to leave something so I can text really long sentences and notes.&nbsp;</p><br></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;"><span id="expanderSign">+</span></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="w-row page_wide_row header">
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div class="no_space_div"><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>STATUS</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>PICKUP</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>DROPOFF</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>COURIER</h5></div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h5>&nbsp;</h5></div>
  </div>
</div>



  <div class="w-row page_wide_row">
    <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
      <div>?</div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>PICKING&nbsp;UP</p></div>
    <div><p>NOW</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><a href="#" class="w-button">Button Text</a></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>WhiteGLove</p></div>
    <div><p>34494 Washington Ave</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>Austin,&nbsp;TX</p></div>
      <div><p>231-444-5555</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>ORDER&nbsp;# 12345</p></div>
      <div><p>1 small/medium package</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>John&nbsp;Anderson</p></div>
    <div><p>3456 Elm Street</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>New York, New York</p></div>
      <div><p>312-444-2323</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>MEMO: Leave at front door.</p></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-2 no_space_column">
    <div><p>Will Roth</p></div>
    <div><p>123-564-9876</p></div>
    <div class="expanderContent" style="display:none">
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
      <div><p>NOTES: This is a really long note about how and where to leave something so I can text really long sentences and notes.&nbsp;</p><br></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
      <div></div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="w-col w-col-01 no_space_column">
    <div><h4 id="expanderHead" style="cursor:pointer;"><span id="expanderSign">+</span></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div><p>&nbsp;</p></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
    <div></div>
  </div>
</div>




</div>
```

==== UPDATE ========

Probably not much help as it won't run in JSFiddle but does on my webserver.

https://jsfiddle.net/L98q71kg/

Comment: Could you make a code snippet or jsfiddle with what you already have?

Comment: Either add **Complete** code or create live demo on [jsfiddle](https://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: looks like you are having multiple elements with same id.. how many elements have the id `#expanderHead` or `#expanderSign`

Comment: can you share your html code

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/L98q71kg/

Comment: Will be hundreds of #expanderHead or #expanderSign. This is going to hold rows and rows of data.

Comment: But in your code, there is only one `expanderHead` and so many `expanderContent`s.. according to your logic, there must be one `expanderHead` for every corresponding `expanderContent`. Modify your HTML first.

Comment: Updated on JSFiddle.

Answer (score 0):

The code has multiple issues. The reuse of ID's is one so need to switch to classes if you want to use the same name.

Traversing the hierarchy in the current way is not correct. The siblings in the code are not siblings you want.

1) Change all the id's to classes

2) Use the following JS

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $(".expanderHead").click(function(){
    //$(".expanderContent").slideToggle('1200', "linear", function () {
    $(this).closest('div').parent('.w-col.w-col-01.no_space_column').parent('.w-row.page_wide_row').children(".w-col-2").children('.expanderContent').slideToggle('1200', "linear", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    if ($(this).children(":first").text() == "+"){
      $(this).children(":first").html("−")
    }
    else {
      $(this).children(":first").text("+")
    }
  });
});
```

Answer (score -1):

The way to do this is using the keyword 'this'. It looks like this:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
  $("#expanderHead").click(function(){
    $(this).slideToggle('2000', "linear", function () {
        // Animation complete.
    });
    if ($(this).text() == "+"){
      $(this).html("−");
    }
    else {
      $(this).text("+");
    }
  });
});
```

jQuery is kind enough to bind the scope of the callback you setup for the click handler to the element that was clicked on which is why this approach works.

Comment: 'This' doesn't work. Inside the hidden div, that holds all the sub divs, I have 5 divs that are of class . expanderContent  so a 1 to 5 ratio of expanderHead to .expandContents.  So one click on expanderHead I need to find .expanderHeads>parent>siblings>children with .expanderContent and the tell them to slideToggle).

Comment: Ok I think I misread your post. I thought you wanted to do things to the element that was clicked. I guess I'm not understanding what the issue is. Sounds like you know which nodes you want to edit.